# Can you help me find the harmony for the following melody?

Tags: theory, chords, composition

I've recently composed a melody and I've been struggling to find a suitable harmony for it. 
For now I've got the harmony as Cm, Gm, Fm, G - Cm, G, D#aug5, Fm

Chords change every two beats.

[image]

Comment: Harmonically, the melody it doesn't go anywhere. You could harmonize the whole thing with 4 bars of C minor. Your chord sequence doesn't seem to "go anywhere" either - it seems like a "random" sequence of chords.

Comment: I'd likely switch up the chords even more often than every 2 beats (e.g. use Fm-Cm in the 3rd and 4th beats of Bar 4), but I agree with 4 bars of Cm more than the question asker's proposed harmonization. The 1st and 2nd beats of Bar 2 fit Cm a lot more strongly than Fm, as the only notes it contains are C, Eb, G, and B--and Cm is C-Eb-G, while Fm is F-Ab-C.

Comment: @dekkadeci How about Cm on the first and second beat and Fm on 3rd and G on 4th?

Answer (score 2):

Schoenberg said he wouldn't give his students assignments that asked them to harmonize a given melody, because it was too hard, or add a melody to a given chord progression, because it was too easy.  Rather, melody and harmony must be conceptualized together.  Unfortunately, you are the only one who can decide on the harmony for your own melody so it can sound the way you imagine it.  If you are having difficulty figure out which chords are *possibilities*, you can first look at the triads and 7th chords the melody notes belong to.  Try them out and experiment to see which ones "fit" the idea in your head.